# iPhone camera can't set long exposure duration

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I am having a problem with setting custom exposure duration.
According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:ISO:completionHandler:) the only way to set exposure duration is with method `setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:ISO:completionHandler:`. But when I set any value higher than 0.07 and the image is taken exposure time has value 0.06666666666666667 although maxExposureDuration property of `AVCaptureDevice` returns that max value can be 0.5 seconds.

Can exposure duration be in collision with other camera properties?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Code:

```
@try
{
    NSError* error;
    [self.captureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error];

    if (!error)
    {
        // Setup of other properties

        if ([self.captureDevice isExposureModeSupported:selectedExposureMode])
        {
            if (selectedExposureMode == AVCaptureExposureModeCustom) {
                [self.captureDevice setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:exposureTimeValue ISO:isoValue completionHandler:^(CMTime syncTime) {}];
            }
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",exception);
}
@finally
{
    [self.captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: What is isoValue?

Comment: @BrandonA isoValue is float number between `self.captureDevice.activeFormat.minISO` and `self.captureDevice.activeFormat.maxISO`. A value of `AVCaptureISOCurrent` can be used to indicate that the caller does not wish to specify a value for ISO.

Answer (score 2):

I test exposure duration = 0.5, which is working, I did *setExposureMode* before changing the duration.

```
[self.captureDevice setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeCustom];
[self.captureDevicesetExposureModeCustomWithDuration:CMTimeMake( 1, 2 ) ISO:iso completionHandler:^(CMTime syncTime) {}];
```

Comment: yes, but if you check captureDevice.exposureDuration it will be 67ms

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is the problem. If you want to change exposure mode (Locked, ContinuousAutoExposure, Custom) you need to reset all camera settings, session, preview layer, still image output, basically setup camera like the first time.